# Keycloak policies for user management not working

Tags: keycloak

I tried to configure a support group that has access to a certain group of customers but not all so i created a `new_user_group` and a `support_group` (this group has `real-management` roles to view and manage users so i can see those `admin-console` menus) and added policies, such that the `support_group` can only see and manage that group and users of that `new_user_group` but not those of `user_group`. Unfortunately after logging in with a user of `support_group` i can see all users and groups not only those of the `new_user_group`.

I already used the Authorization Evaluator of the `realm-management` client. The funny thing is that if i choose the new user of the support_group and the user_group resource with view scope it correctly determines that access should be denied.

Am I missing something? Maybe the problem is that the new_support_group does have realm-management roles like view-users? But if i remove those roles i am not able to see any menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to give the group that the policies should apply to the role `query_users` for the `realm_management` client. Do not add `manage_useres` role to the group as this would ignore any policies.